# Arrary of structures error

Tags: c

I can't seem to understand how to copy from the user input into the array structure, I have researched all over this site and I have found lots of variations but not an example that is helping me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct member 
{
    char name;
    int age;
    char state;
};

int main() 
{
     int i,r,iyr;
     char name, stabr;
     struct member record[49];

    for(r=0;r<49;r++)
    {
        printf ( "\nEnter the name of the family member \n");
        printf ("\nCount is %d \n",r+1);
        scanf ( "%s", &name);
        strcpy(record[r].name, name);
        printf ( "\nEnter the age of the family member \n");
        scanf ( "%d", &iyr);
        record[r].age=iyr;
        printf ( "\nEnter the abbreviated state name of the family member \n");
        scanf ( "%s", &stabr);
        strcpy(record[r].state, stabr);

    }
    for(i=0; i<49; i++)
     {
         printf("     Records of Family : %d \n", i+1);
         printf(" Name is: %s \n", record[i].name);
         printf(" Age is: %d \n", record[i].age);
         printf(" State is: %s\n\n",record[i].state);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `char name` is ONE character, not a string.

Comment: I get more than a dozen warnings when I compile your code.

Comment: Major fault is `struct member` has no string storage, `name` and `state` are single `char`, as are local vars `name` and `stabr` in `main()`.

Comment: With all your code, compile with **warnings enabled**. If using `gcc`, that is `gcc -Wall -Wextra`, for other compilers, check the reference manual. With `gcc` you can also add `-pedantic` for basically all possible warnings. Then *read* and *fix* ALL warnings. They are built into the compiler for a reason.

Comment: Thanks you all pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You were using single char for storing a name and state.
you are not allocating memory.
When you are allocating memory use pointer notation than array because array will have const pointer which cannot be modified.
Remember to free the memory.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct member
{
    char name[50]; // You were using single character for storing a name of multiple character and state
    int age;
    char state[50];
}members;
int main(void)
{
    //When you are allocating memory use pointer notation than array
    //because array will have const pointer which cannot be modified
    members *record = (members *)malloc(49*sizeof(members)); // you are not allocating memory
    int r;
    for(r=0;r<2;r++)
    {
        printf ( "\nEnter the name of the family member \n");
        printf ("\nCount is %d \n",r+1);
        scanf ( "%s", &record[r].name);
        printf ( "\nEnter the age of the family member \n");
        scanf ( "%d", &record[r].age);
        printf ( "\nEnter the abbreviated state name of the family member \n");
        scanf ( "%s", &record[r].state);

    }
    for(r=0; r<2; r++)
    {
        printf("     Records of Family : %d \n", r+1);
        printf(" Name is: %s \n", record[r].name);
        printf(" Age is: %d \n", record[r].age);
        printf(" State is: %s\n\n",record[r].state);
    }

    free(record); // Remember to free the memory

    return 0;
}
```